# Prevent process from overwriting files

Tags: linux, files, filenames, concurrency

#### The setting

Let's say I have an executable file, let's call it `program`, whose source code is unavailable (maybe proprietary/legacy).

Each time this program is executed, it generates a file, let's call it `file.txt`, always with the same name and always on the same directory, depending on the command line argument passed to `program`.

#### The problem

I want to execute several instances of `program` concurrently. This may happen in a context in which `program` lives in a server that is listening for requests to execute `program` from the clients.

The problem is that it seems impossible, as long as both instances would be writing to the same `file.txt`, and hence probably, this file will end up being corrupt.

#### Possible solution ideas

- Can I somehow redirect `program`'s output to a file with a unique name (remember that the source is missing)?
- Can I somehow "sandbox" `program` to make it behave as if executed on a separate file system (with negligible overhead)?
- I have heard about `LD_PRELOAD`, but I don't know if it just works for overriding C standard library functions or if it also works for overriding Linux system calls in general.

Any idea?

Comment: This behaviour of the »program« is typical for avoiding to be run in multiple instances at the same time. Are you sure the software is designed that is allowed more than one instance?

Comment: No, it was for sure not designed for that purpose, but I was wondering if it could still be used for that by wrapping it into another program, or with some other kind of workaround that let me change the file name before the file is actually written into disk.

Comment: Maybe you could create a Docker container containing this program. Then you can launch as many containers as you like, they'll all be completely self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

> Each time this program is executed, it generates a file, let's call it "file.txt", always with the same name and always on the same directory, which is different depending on the command line argument passed to program.

If the program is a dynamic executable, you could use function interposition via [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795) to make it write the file in a different location (e.g., one specified by an environment variable). This will mean intercepting calls to `open`, checking to see if the `open` call is for `file.txt`, and then running an appropriate alternative.

If the program is started as a systemd service, you can use the [`PrivateMounts`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateMounts=) option to run it in its own mount namespace, and mount a unique directory in which it can write `file.txt`.

You can, as @glennjackman suggested in a comment, also arrange to run the process in a container: this is effectively the same as the previous solution, but instead of systemd you're using a container runtime like Docker or Podman to set up up the mount namespace.

---

Of the above options, running it inside a container is probably going to be operationally the easiest.

---

> I have heard about "LD_PRELOAD" but I don't if it just works for overriding C standard library functions or if it also works for overriding Linux system calls in general.

Function interposition via `LD_PRELOAD` only lets you intercept function calls, not syscalls. But this is usually just fine: when your code calls `open`, it's not directly calling the `open` syscall; it's calling a glibc wrapper function that in turn calls the syscall.

Comment: Thank you (and everyone), I will give a try to each of the alternatives, update the question and, hopefully, accept the answer.